# MS Outlook 2019 can't get self signed macro to be enabled

Tags: outlook, certificate

I just installed Outlook 2019 on a new computer.  I had things running correctly on the other one but I can't get the macro to be enabled on the new no matter what I have done.  I tried to import the cert into the root but (at least the way I did it) it is not enabled and running.  All very odd but I need some guidance on how to get this working on the new system.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the same certificate which was used for signing to the Trusted root on the new machine.

Comment: I created a self-signed cert on the new machine and signed the code.  I then get the cert inserted into the Trusted Publishers.  When I have outlook set to confirm all macros, it never enables the option to trust any from this publisher.  Its all very odd.

Comment: Why should I need to use the same cert as on the old machine?  It is the same code but this is not compiled code but interpreted, so I wouldn't see this as required, would it?

Comment: Why do you need to use certs? Does the code work correctly without any certs? Did you have a chance to change Trust Center settings?

Comment: the cert allows Outlook to open without having to click on "allow".  Okay, I'm lazy. :)